# How does this function change the parameter passed to it?

Tags: c

I seem to be lost with this Fourier Transform function. There's a sample program that I have but don't understand. The ggFFTworksp contains the data and fftFrameSize is simply framesize of the data. I don't understand how the function is supposed to put the FFT version of the data into the fftBuffer if there is no part in the code where fftBuffer is actually edited or manipulated. Thank you in advance!

The function call is this:

```
static float gFFTworksp[2*MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
long fftFrameSize;    
smbFft(gFFTworksp, fftFrameSize, -1);
```

The function in question is this:

```
void smbFft(float *fftBuffer, long fftFrameSize, long sign)
/* 
    FFT routine, (C)1996 S.M.Bernsee. Sign = -1 is FFT, 1 is iFFT (inverse)
    Fills fftBuffer[0...2*fftFrameSize-1] with the Fourier transform of the
    time domain data in fftBuffer[0...2*fftFrameSize-1]. The FFT array takes
    and returns the cosine and sine parts in an interleaved manner, ie.
    fftBuffer[0] = cosPart[0], fftBuffer[1] = sinPart[0], asf. fftFrameSize
    must be a power of 2. It expects a complex input signal (see footnote 2),
    ie. when working with 'common' audio signals our input signal has to be
    passed as {in[0],0.,in[1],0.,in[2],0.,...} asf. In that case, the transform
    of the frequencies of interest is in fftBuffer[0...fftFrameSize].
*/
{
    float wr, wi, arg, *p1, *p2, temp;
    float tr, ti, ur, ui, *p1r, *p1i, *p2r, *p2i;
    long i, bitm, j, le, le2, k;

    for (i = 2; i < 2*fftFrameSize-2; i += 2) {
        for (bitm = 2, j = 0; bitm < 2*fftFrameSize; bitm <<= 1) {
            if (i & bitm) j++;
            j <<= 1;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            p1 = fftBuffer+i; p2 = fftBuffer+j;
            temp = *p1; *(p1++) = *p2;
            *(p2++) = temp; temp = *p1;
            *p1 = *p2; *p2 = temp;
        }
    }
    for (k = 0, le = 2; k < (long)(log(fftFrameSize)/log(2.)+.5); k++) {
        le <<= 1;
        le2 = le>>1;
        ur = 1.0;
        ui = 0.0;
        arg = M_PI / (le2>>1);
        wr = cos(arg);
        wi = sign*sin(arg);
        for (j = 0; j < le2; j += 2) {
            p1r = fftBuffer+j; p1i = p1r+1;
            p2r = p1r+le2; p2i = p2r+1;
            for (i = j; i < 2*fftFrameSize; i += le) {
                tr = *p2r * ur - *p2i * ui;
                ti = *p2r * ui + *p2i * ur;
                *p2r = *p1r - tr; *p2i = *p1i - ti;
                *p1r += tr; *p1i += ti;
                p1r += le; p1i += le;
                p2r += le; p2i += le;
            }
            tr = ur*wr - ui*wi;
            ui = ur*wi + ui*wr;
            ur = tr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `p1 = fftBuffer+i; p2 = fftBuffer+j;` and then these pointers are dereferenced and the values they point to are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line:

```
p1 = fftBuffer+i; p2 = fftBuffer+j;
```

p1 and p2 become pointers that point to the memory location of the fftBuffer array. And in these lines:

```
*(p2++) = temp; temp = *p1;
*p1 = *p2; *p2 = temp;
```

the values in these memory locations are being changed.

Comment: Oh now I understand!! :D Thank you very much! I deeply appreciate your help!